# Fast tolower function

Tags: c++

C++ Standard Library functions like std::tolower, std::isalpha, etc. could be quite slow when it comes to large texts and handling locales.

So, I decided to have fast tolower function, caching the values. They are blazingly fast.

*Assumption: nobody will intentionally try to hack the code, trying all possible and impossible ways to call tolower_fast before cache is filled. I assume that tolower_fast will be called much later in common program flow from function main.*

**Performace measurement**

On [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/KzfjhaE3a) test it gives:

> Duration of std::tolower = 0.17513s
>
> Duration of tolower_fast = 0.000366216s
>
> Duration of tolower_fast2 = 1.38e-06s

On my PC with VS 2022 release:

> Duration std::tolower = 1.46942s
>
> Duration tolower_fast = 0.0001968s
>
> Duration tolower_fast2 = 5.35e-05s

(Actually, tolower_fast and tolower_fast2 don't differ so much between each other, this is measurement error).

So, real performance difference is about 1000 times in Release on local PC. Real large texts processing improved from minutes to seconds.

**The code**

I see many ways to implement caching, for example the following two ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f11bK93aa)):

```
#include <locale>

const std::locale locale(""); // Any reasonable locale

static struct tolower_cache_t {
    char cache[UCHAR_MAX + 1];

    tolower_cache_t() {
        for (size_t c = 0; c <= UCHAR_MAX; ++c)
            cache[c] = std::tolower((char)c, locale);
    }
} tolower_cache;

inline char tolower_fast(char ch) {
    return tolower_cache.cache[ch];
}

class ToLower
{
public:
    ToLower() {
        for (size_t c = 0; c <= UCHAR_MAX; ++c)
            cache[c] = std::tolower((char)c, locale);
    }

    bool operator()(char c) const { return cache[c]; }
private:
    bool cache[UCHAR_MAX + 1];
};

static ToLower tolower_fast2;

int main()
{
    char c = 'A';
    char lc1 = tolower_fast(c);
    char lc2 = tolower_fast2(c);
}
```

The first one uses object and a function, the second one uses functional object. I guess that from compilation perspective (when it comes to call *tolower* itself) they should give the similar code.
The questions are:

1. Which of two implementations is better? I mean here potential problems and maintainability.
2. Are there any issues with the approach and code?
3. Is there a better way to do this which will still guarantee cache filling before *tolower_fast*?

Comment: How fast is it really? Did you benchmark your cached versions against simply calling `std::tolower()` uncached? Without any real numbers to back it up, a statement like "blazingly fast" is meaningless, and potentially even completely false.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, of course, I measured. The question has been updated. I was sure the difference would be obvious so I decided not to overcomplicate the question, since std::tolower call goes to operation system level (for each character!) to see the locale and translate properly. It is really slow.

Comment: Always enable compiler optimization when doing benchmarks. The numbers change significantly if you add `-O2`. Also, there is a huge difference between calling `std::tolower()` with one or two arguments. If you call it without a locale, it will be faster than your cached version (see [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/xxvv966Mr)).

Comment: @G.Sliepen, I need the locale, since I use non-English characters both in source texts and during the execution (I use non-unicode char since memory and performance matter on these sizes). Is there a chance to handle this without locale? Should I create a question on SO on this?

Comment: Are you only interested in 8-bit locales? What about multibyte locales and Unicode?

Comment: @G.Sliepen, my character set (Russian) fits to the 8-bit locale, which gives me a chance to reduce memory footprint at least two times relative to the UTF-16. I am not sure how arrays of multibyte works, I assume that array should allocate memory for the largest possible multibyte. Actually, I am interested in both possible solutions 8-bit locale and UNICODE locale, since latter simplifies debugging of local characters and strings, but 8-bit locale is primary for me because of memory footprint.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, thank you for the hint with -O2, this is one of the differences between godbolt and local compilations; I've updated the values from godbolt, now they are close to mine (with locale). The funny thing, by the way with those 'tolower_fast' and 'tolower_fast2' measurements; if you swap them in the testing code (which run first) the resulting timing will stay the same - first larger and second smaller. Some kind of measurement precision error, I guess.

Comment: If you know what locale you are going to use you can most of the time just do bit mask operations to implement to_lower. It might end up being faster than using a cache.

Comment: Today, you're either using ASCII (with a pair of comparisons and a bitmask) or Unicode (probably with a hash table). For 8-bit locales (obsolete or nearly so), you probably want a lookup table.

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat, unfortunately this doesn't work for [Russian Code page 866](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866). The relation between upper and lower case characters is not so straightforward here and will involve too many if-checks. The main disadvantage of course will come when I decide to switch to another locale. Having here and there the code which will break without any warning on locale change is dangerous. Will, I can check locale and fire warning, but anyway, this is not robust code.

Comment: @Davislor, lookup table is exactly what the cache implements. For  [Russian Code page 866](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866) it could be more than 2 comparisons; this table is a little bit tricky. I understand that 8-locales are obsolete, but doubling (or increasing 4 times) the size of requested RAM will make text-processing algorithms memory-bound way too fast.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, on the "*Also, there is a huge difference between calling std::tolower() with one or two arguments. If you call it without a locale, it will be faster than your cached version*". I tried on local PC with VS 2024 with `std::locale::global(std::locale("Russian"));` and `std::tolower()` with one argument, no changes in performance at all. I tried to reproduce this on godbolt, but clang doesn't accept any Russian-related local I've tried and x64 msvc doesn't produce output on godbolt, so I have no chance to try there. So, still slow on VS 2024 even with 1 argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Which of two implementations is better? I mean here potential problems and maintainability.

There is a third way. You don't need `struct`s to build the cache, instead you can just use free functions:

```
static auto make_tolower_cache() {
    std::array<char, UCHAR_MAX + 1> cache;
    for (std::size_t c = 0; c < cache.size(); ++c)
        cache[c] = std::tolower(static_cast<char>(c), locale);
    return cache;
}

static auto tolower_cache = make_tolower_cache();

inline char tolower_fast(char ch) {
    return tolower_cache[ch];
}
```

> 2. Are there any issues with the approach and code?

It only works for simple 8-bit locales. For Unicode, especially if it is encoded using UTF-8, you will need a different approach.

> 3. Is there a better way to do this which will still guarantee cache filling before *tolower_fast*?

You can declare a `static` array inside a function. When that function is then called for the first time, it will be initialized. Subsequent times it doesn't have to do the full initialization anymore, but there is some overhead because it still needs to check somehow whether it is the first time the function is called:

```
inline char tolower_fast(char ch) {
    static auto tolower_cache = make_tolower_cache();
    return tolower_cache[ch];
}
```

So if performance is the most important thing, then that is not the way to go. There are various other ways to address this: call a function early in `main()` to initialize the cache, never call `tolower_fast()` before `main()` starts, ensure the link order is such that a global `static` cache is initialized early enough, and so on.

Note that if you need even more perfomance, then search for or create a function that lowers multiple characters at a time using SIMD instructions.

Comment: Thank you for the clue with SIMD instructions. Currently my code processes 3Gb file in 0.177 seconds on my local PC, which is good enough for the moment, but as soon as I see another case to speed up, I will try SIMD. One issue for my and your versions, as I understand that in case we need it in header file to inline the function call, we will have static array duplicated across all cpp files which include this header file. I guess the solution from *Toby Speight* should help in this case to make this instantiation a bit more manageable.

Answer (score 5):

### Don’t Reinvent the Wheel

Your standard library almost certainly already uses a pre-filled lookup table that’s faster than this.

### But if You Do

#### Use a `constexpr` Array

The lookup table contains only 256 constant values, which are known at compile time.  They should be declared as compile-time constants that the compiler can perform constant-folding optimization on.  There should not be a cache at all, which you call `tolower` on every element and fill.  Initialize the table with constant expressions.

#### Make it for a Single Locale

If you really need to change the locale dynamically and have the same function work, use the standard library `tolower`, or if you don’t, keep a `struct` of lookup tables for each locale you support, and give your library an initialization function that selects the locale data you currently want to use.

#### Putting it all Together

The implementation is very simple:

```cpp
static constexpr unsigned char tolower_table_cp866[256] = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
    0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F,
    0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0x2C, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x2F,
    0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3A, 0x3B, 0x3C, 0x3D, 0x3E, 0x3F,
    0x40, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6A, 0x6B, 0x6C, 0x6D, 0x6E, 0x6F,
    0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7A, 0x5B, 0x5C, 0x5D, 0x5E, 0x5F,
    0x60, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6A, 0x6B, 0x6C, 0x6D, 0x6E, 0x6F,
    0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7A, 0x5B, 0x5C, 0x7D, 0x7E, 0x7F,
    0xA0, 0xA1, 0xA2, 0xA3, 0xA4, 0xA5, 0xA6, 0xA7, 0xA8, 0xA9, 0xAA, 0xAB, 0xAC, 0xAD, 0xAE, 0xAF,
    0xE0, 0xE1, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0xE4, 0xE5, 0xE6, 0xE7, 0xE8, 0xE9, 0xEA, 0xEB, 0xEC, 0xED, 0xEE, 0xEF,
    0xA0, 0xA1, 0xA2, 0xA3, 0xA4, 0xA5, 0xA6, 0xA7, 0xA8, 0xA9, 0xAA, 0xAB, 0xAC, 0xAD, 0xAE, 0xAF,
    0xB0, 0xB1, 0xB2, 0xB3, 0xB4, 0xB5, 0xB6, 0xB7, 0xB8, 0xB9, 0xBA, 0xBB, 0xBC, 0xBD, 0xBE, 0xBF,
    0xC0, 0xC1, 0xC2, 0xC3, 0xC4, 0xC5, 0xC6, 0xC7, 0xC8, 0xC9, 0xCA, 0xCB, 0xCC, 0xCD, 0xCE, 0xCF,
    0xD0, 0xD1, 0xD2, 0xD3, 0xD4, 0xD5, 0xD6, 0xD7, 0xD8, 0xD9, 0xDA, 0xDB, 0xDC, 0xDD, 0xDE, 0xDF,
    0xE0, 0xE1, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0xE4, 0xE5, 0xE6, 0xE7, 0xE8, 0xE9, 0xEA, 0xEB, 0xEC, 0xED, 0xEE, 0xEF,
    0xF1, 0xF1, 0xF3, 0xF3, 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xF7, 0xF7, 0xF8, 0xF9, 0xFA, 0xFB, 0xFC, 0xFD, 0xFE, 0xFF
};

constexpr unsigned char tolower_cp866(const unsigned char c) noexcept {
    return tolower_table_cp866[c];
}
```

With this implementation, the very basic test driver:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

using std::exit, std::uint8_t;
using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

constexpr auto upper_sv = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8A\x8B\x8C\x8D\x8E\x8F"
    "\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9A\x9B\x9C\x9D\x9E\x9F"
    "\xF0\xF2\xF4\xF6"sv;

constexpr auto lower_sv = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    "\xA0\xA1\xA2\xA3\xA4\xA5\xA6\xA7\xA8\xA9\xAA\xAB\xAC\xAD\xAE\xAF"
    "\xE0\xE1\xE2\xE3\xE4\xE5\xE6\xE7\xE8\xE9\xEA\xEB\xEC\xED\xEE\xEF"
    "\xF1\xF3\xF5\xF7"sv;


int main() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < upper_sv.size(); ++i) {
        if (tolower_cp866((unsigned char)upper_sv[i]) != (unsigned char)lower_sv[i]) {
            std::cerr << i << ": " << (unsigned)(uint8_t)tolower_cp866((unsigned char)upper_sv[i]) << " != " << (unsigned)(uint8_t)lower_sv[i] << '\n';
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < upper_sv.size(); ++i) {
        if (tolower_cp866((unsigned char)lower_sv[i]) != (unsigned char)lower_sv[i]) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    std::cout << tolower_cp866('A') << '\n';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On this example, the string comparisons can inline the calls to `tolower_cp866`, and most compliers can completely optimize the call `tolower_cp866('A')` to the constant `'a'`.

Try it [on Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/ejbPqv434)

Comment: Thank you for the input. Before I provide my opinion on it, let me double check that you got me correctly. Here are my conditions: (1) there are many functions like that, to_lower, to_upper, isapha (see much more here: [cctype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype) and this is not the end of the day); (2) Version which uses locale is slow by measurement; (3) Benchmark-oriented tests like tolower_cp866('A') is not my case since I need to process large texts. (And I could change code page, keeping only one per build). Are you still sure this solution is any better?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Yes, I think it is. Let’s go through them. 1: Each function like that takes only a 256-byte table and a single line of code, which is trivial.

Comment: @DamirTenishev 2: This version ought to be much faster, especially on constant strings. If you need multiple 8-bit locales, you could represent each character set with an `enum`, and use that as an index into an array of `struct` holding all the tables and other data your reimplementation needs. This could also be `constexpr`.

Comment: @DamirTenishev 3: This function is a drop-in replacement that can be used on a string, including a loop, an algorithm, or a range adaptor. Here, I also demonstrate how to use it to do a case-insensitive string comparison.

Comment: Basically, making the lookup table and the function `constexpr` rather than initializing it at runtime enables some more optimizations.

Comment: The first sentence is debatable.  While this may be practical for the `char` version of `std::tolower()`, it's infeasible for `wchar_t`, at least on platforms where that's 32 bits wide.  I haven't checked, but I'd guess that implementations generally use the same approach throughout rather than specialising for the different character types.

Comment: Thank you again and let me step in with my questions and concerns since the length of comment is limited, I will post them one by one. To be honest, your approach is most arguable for me personally, so in order to learn, I will be scrupulous here, since I see your points and benefits and like the overall idea, I am just not sure yet, that this is the best place to apply it. To be on the same page, I don’t need many locales (at least now) simultaneously. So, now I will be working with only locale only, but it could be different for different builds.(to be continued...)

Comment: (1) Your first statement under “Don’t Reinvent the Wheel” contradicts the measurements, I’ve published in the question; the standard library function is at least 2000 times slower than my function when used with 8-bit locale under Win x64. So, we have the task to be solved when it comes to large texts. (2) I tested all approaches on my local PC with 3Gb text file and `std::transform/std::execution::par_unseq`. While `std::tolower` take 33.81 seconds, all our functions (your and mine) took 0.177 sec each (191 times faster even being memory-bound here) with one difference, (to be continued...)

Comment: if calls from `std::transform` are not wrapped to lambda (just passed as a function), tolower_fast and tolower_cp866 takes 0.276 seconds and tolower_fast still takes 0.177 seconds. Anyway, on real data the approaches run with the same performance being more memory-bound on data rather CPU/memory bound of function. So, no real difference to complicate the code. Even if any, tenths of a second in not what I would fight for in this case, after I won more than 33.5 seconds.

Comment: (3) My function takes the same 256-byte table and a single line of code, so I don’t see much difference here; is it? (4) I don’t see real reason to use them on constant strings unless you want to build-in the texts to be processed, as well. I am kidding, of course, here. (5) My function object and function could be used as drop-ins, as well. I don’t see much difference here.

Comment: (6) You never showed how to get this table and this is kind of extra work to be done for every function I would need and for every code page I would need. Having dozens of functions (this is the key) and dozens of code pages, I will have to write some extra code for this. Not too much hard, but what’s about Occam’s razor?

Comment: (7) I see this approach here and there in different projects and I use it very rarely, like with MD5 checksum coefficients, FFT coefficients in some algorithms, some expected results; mostly for things which is hard to calculate and mostly which we take as granted. For other things, I prefer to have caching even if it takes time, I do it once and store on disk. But I avoid putting large look-up tables, images, etc. in code. The main reason is readability. Despite the fact I see profits in your approach it verges with “evil of hard-coded values”, so I am in twenty minds here.

Comment: @TobySpeight Implementations that use `char32_t` as `wchar_t` still have a maximum value of 1,114,112, so even a complete table would need no more entries than that. As I believe I said in a comment to the question, I think how I would implement that is, a hash table with a perfect hash function, storing only those codepoints whose lowercase value is different.

Answer (score 2):

The two implementations do different things - `ToLower` invoking `std::isalpha()` is very misleading.

Otherwise, the second version is much better, as it doesn't depend on the global variable `tolower_cache`.  That said, there's no good reason that the lookup table can't be a `static` variable within the function.

The second version still depends on a global variable (`locale`).  I'd pass that as a constructor argument, so that we can easily create translators for different locales:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cctype>
#include <limits>
#include <locale>
#include <ranges>

class ToLower
{
    std::array<char, std::numeric_limits<char>::max() + 1> table = {};

public:
    explicit ToLower(const std::locale& locale = {})
    {
        set_locale(locale);
    }

    void set_locale(const std::locale& locale)
    {
        auto const func = [&locale](char c){return std::tolower(c, locale); };
        std::ranges::copy(std::views::iota(0u, table.size())
                          | std::views::transform(func),
                          table.begin());
    }

    char operator()(char c) const { return table[c]; }
};
```

We can demonstrate the different locales using Turkish (which doesn't downcase `I` due to the lack of a single-byte `ı`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string sample = "CODE REVIEW";
    std::string output = sample;
    std::ranges::transform(sample, output.begin(), ToLower{std::locale::classic()});
    std::cout << output << '\n';
    std::ranges::transform(sample, output.begin(), ToLower{std::locale{"tr_TR.UTF-8"}});
    std::cout << output << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
code review
code revIew
```

Unfortunately, the table-based approach only really works for single-byte character sets.  Populating and using a 16GB table of all `wchar_t` loses all the gains we made - which is why `std::tolower()` doesn't work that way.

Comment: *"the second version is much better, as it doesn't depend on the global variable `tolower_cache`"* No, but the second version does depend on the global variable `tolower_fast2`, so I don't see how this is any better. It has most of the same issues as the first one, but you are right that if you pass it a locale as a parameter, you can have multiple instances of it, which the first version doesn't support.

Comment: Well, `tolower_fast2` could be made `const` as it stands, but `tolower_cache` can't without more work.

Comment: You can just add `const` right in front of `tolower_cache` in OP's code.

Comment: "*The two implementations do different things - ToLower invoking std::isalpha() is very misleading*". Thank you for catching this, this is typo, since initially this was implemented in two different ways and putting these two fragments together I missed to change the name. Of course, it meant to be std::tolower. Despite the rules, I changed the code since this is, indeed too much confusing. Feel free to update your answer, removing this part and thank you again. Let me address the answer itself in a separate comment.

Comment: Special thanks to you for the example with the parametrization and ranges. It really helps. Not sure this version will illuminate the need for a kind of global variable for the table, because in your case table initialization is needed on each instantiation; although it is indeed not too much CPU work, but having it initialized once could be better. On the other hand if all this work is localized in couple of functions which are rarely called and if we have many locales, it is definitely the best approach. Thank you again.