# Natural language text fast tokenizer

Tags: c++, parsing

Could you please conduct code review for the code below and suggest some improvements?

**Functional specification**

Implement a function for fast tokenization of text in char[] buffer handling some natural language specifics below:

1. Consider ‘ ‘ (space) as a delimiter, keeping a way to extends the list of delimiters later.
2. Extract stable collocations like “i.e.”, “etc.”, “…” as a single lexem.
3. In case word contains characters like ‘-‘ and ‘’’ (examples: semi-column, cat’s) return the whole construct as a whole lexem.
4. Return sequences of numbers (integers without signs) as a single lexem.

Performance is critical, since the amount of data is huge. The function must be thread-safe.

**Design**

Since performance is critical, the function work with raw pointers to const char. It gets the argument as the reference to the pointer to the place where from it should start parsing and updates this pointer, moving to the position past the read lexem.

Since initial characters could be delimiters, function returns the real starting position of the lexem found.

**Concerns on the current implementation**

Most likely, for such tasks the [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) library should be used, but I am not sure if this “write-only” language (regex) (for me at least; you write once and can’t read and maintain it at all, rewriting from scratch every time) will be extendable when new requirements come. If I am wrong, I will be thankful for the maintainable version with the regex.

Another concern on the regex usage is performance. The code is expected to work with locales and this could be [quite slow](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289151/fast-tolower-function) if underlying regex implementation somehow uses isalpha, etc.

I feel that with `std::ranges` this could be implemented simpler, so is case of any suggestions, please, share.

I feel that main loop could be simplified and nested loop at the end could be removed, but can't find better solution for now.

With all these static vectors and intention to make it configurable and extendable in future, I am in two minds if to make a class or namespace from this in order to being able to configure with delimiters, stable lexems, inwords lexems, etc. Would it be extendability or overengineering?

**The code**

The fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/86dPY963x)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

// Returs lexem start point or nullptr if lexem not found
// Moves the passed pointer to the position past the lexem
inline const char* get_lexem(const char*& p)
{
    const static std::vector delimiters = { ' ' }; // Could be extened to many different delimiters
    const static std::vector<const char*> stable_lexems = { "i.e.", "etc.", "..." }; // Planned to be externally configurable
    const static std::vector<char> inword_lexems = { '-', '\'' }; // Not sure how to process this better

    const char* start = p;

    while (*p && p == start) {
        while (delimiters.end() != std::find(delimiters.begin(), delimiters.end(), *p)) {
            ++p;
            if (!*p)
                return nullptr;
        }

        auto it = std::find_if(stable_lexems.begin(), stable_lexems.end(), [&](const char* lexem) {
            size_t length = strlen(lexem);
            return !strncmp(p, lexem, length);
            });

        start = p;

        if (it != stable_lexems.end()) {
            p += strlen(*it);
            return start;
        }

        while (*p && (delimiters.end() == find(delimiters.begin(), delimiters.end(), *p))) {
            const bool is_inword_char = inword_lexems.end() != std::find(inword_lexems.begin(), inword_lexems.end(), *p);

            if (is_inword_char && p != start && isalpha(*(p - 1))) {
                ++p;
                continue;
            }

            if (!isalpha(*p) && !isdigit(*p)) {
                if (p == start) {
                    ++p;
                }
                break;
            }

            ++p;
        }
    }

    return start;
}


int main()
{
    const char sample[] = "Let's conisder this semi-simple sample, i.e. test data with ints: 100, etc. For ... some testing...";

    const char* lexem = nullptr;
    const char* lexem_end = sample;

    while (true) {
        lexem = get_lexem(lexem_end);

        if (!(lexem && lexem != lexem_end))
            break;

        std::string token(lexem, lexem_end - lexem);

        std::cout << token << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but I am still wondering why the mixture of using `std::string` and `char *`. Your `sample` is declared in `std::string`, why not keep it align with `const char*`?

Comment: @JimmyHu, it really doesn't matter. Don't pay much attention to main function here, it is provided only to show the call and make demo runnable. As you can see I take c_str() from it and all the code which deals with the get_lexem works with const char* only. I can't update the code based on rules of the SE/CR, otherwise I'd just replaced the `std::string sample` with `const char sample[]`; it really doesn't matter here.

Comment: @JimmyHu, since the question wasn't answered yet, I've updated the code in the question to cover your concern to avoid future questions on this. I believe, this fits the rules. The code of the function provided for code review has not changed. (Feel free to remove your comments if you will they don't match the code since the changes).

Comment: It's really nice that you included tests, because the code behaves slightly differently than the leading description would entail. In particular, you have hard-coded that any non-alphanumeric character is a delimiter.

Comment: @MatthieuM., not exactly. Any non-alphanumeric character is a lexem. Delimiters are only spaces for now. They don't go to the output as lexems; other non-alphanumeric character do. Anyway, you are correct, this is not documented behaviour, thank you for catching this. I will fix in 3rd revision. Meanwhile in [Rev2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289428/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-2) I've updated the functional specification and made a special note for the code.

Comment: The code assumes single-byte characters.  Is that a safe assumption for your project?  A char[] buffer is commonly used for text even when the encoding may use a variable number of bytes per "character" (e.g., UTF-8).

Comment: Note that the character classification functions like isalpha take an int.  When you pass a char, it'll be promoted.  But if your system uses signed values for char, you run the risk of undefined behavior.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, yes this is the safe assumption. The goal is to work with huge texts so I have to use the smallest size possible to avoid memory bottlenecks. Thank you for pinpointing this, I will put this in the next revision comments to functional specification.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, thank you for the heads up on char/int. This is what *Toby Speight* pointed out in his answer below. I the [rev2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289428/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-2) I moved to std::isalpha, etc, so I believe this should help avoid issues. Anyway, I will monitor this with unit tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Avoid using `char*`

C++ provides much nicer and safer ways to deal with strings and string slices than C's `char*`. Before C++17, I recommend you just use `std::string` where possible. This might cause some unnecessary copies to be made though. Luckily, since C++17 we have [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view); this is just a *view* of another string, it doesn't hold a copy itself.

## Make it work like a range

Wouldn't it be nice if the code in `main()` could be written like this?

```
int main() {
    std::string sample = "Let's consider…";

    for (auto token: tokenize(sample)) {
        std::cout << token << '\n';
    }
}
```

You can do this by making a function `tokenize()` that returns a `class` that has two functions, `begin()` and `end()`, that both return a token iterator. Here is a possible way to do this:

```
class TokenRange {
    std::string_view data;
public:
    class Iterator {
        std::string_view data;
    public:
        Iterator(std::string_view data = {}): data(data) {}
        Iterator& operator++();
        std::string_view operator*() const;
        friend bool operator==(const Iterator&, const Iterator&) = default;
    };

    TokenRange(std::string_view data): data(data) {}

    Iterator begin() {
        return Iterator(data);
    }

    Iterator end() {
        return {};
    }
};
```

So now if you write `tokenize(sample).begin()`, you get a `TokenRange::Iterator` whose member `data` is a view of the whole string `sample`. Now if you try to dereference that iterator using `*`, then you expect it to return the value of the first item in the range, or in this case, the first token. That's most of what you do in `get_lexem()`. So `get_lexem()` can be turned into `TokenRange::Iterator::operator*()`.

Of course, `operator++()` will probably be called soon afterwards, so you want to make sure you don't duplicate most of `operator*()` just to know how much you have to skip over. Find some way to only have to scan for a token once.

While `std::string_view` is more than just a pointer, and you might even need more member variables in `Iterator`, any decent compiler will inline all these things and optimize them away.

Making a standards-compliant iterator is a little bit more work, but you can inherit from [`std::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator). Also see [this tutorial](https://internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp).

## Consider making use of more recent C++ features

Instead of `std::find(delimiters.begin(), delimiters.end(), *p)`, you could write `std::ranges::find(delimiters, *p)` instead. Or even better:

```
while (std::ranges::contains(delimiters, *p)) {
    ++p;
}

if (!*p) {
    …
}
```

Use `std::string_view`'s [`compare()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/compare) member function instead of `strncmp()`, and of course [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/size) insead of `strlen()`. Or if you just want to check if a string begins with a given text, then use [`starts_with()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/starts_with).

## Going full `std::ranges`

It sounds like this should be a problem that could be solved with [`std::ranges`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges). Something like:

```
auto tokens = data
            | std::views::lazy_split(delimiters)
            | …;
```

However, your definition of a token is complex enough that writing it out using just views would either result in some horrible looking code, or it might be very inefficient. If I would go this route, then I would start with a function that maps each charater to some enum that describes which class it belongs to: delimiter, in-word lexem, alphanumerics and other. Then you can use other views to split on delimiters, and use something like [`std::views::adjacent_transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/adjacent_transform_view) to eliminate in-word lexems at the start of a token. Still, checking for stable lexems seems to be hard.

I would probably keep the structure of `get_lexem()`. However, just like you can make a `tokenize()` function that returns a range, you could make your own `tokenize_view()` so you can write:

```
auto tokens = data | tokenize_view();
```

The main advantage of that would be that you could then use that inside a larger pipeline of views.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help here. As was really surprised how fast you've done this code review; it was like you had this implemented before :). I have updated the code according to your recommendations and posted [Rev2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289428/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-2). Could you please check if my understanding is correct? And about `char *` vs `std::string_view`, shame on me, I stepped on this already second time; you already caught this on previous reviews. My concern was performance, but now I see (see in rev2) that this is not the case.

Comment: To keep you posted, I've published the [Rev.3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289472/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-3). Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 5):

## Prefer `<cstring>` to `<string.h>`

The C compatibility headers should only be used for `extern "C"` interfaces.  For C++ programs, use the C++ headers, which definitely declare identifiers in the `std` namespace (e.g. `std::size_t`, `std::strncmp`, `std::strlen`).

Similarly, we should include `<cctype>` to declare `std::isalpha` and `std::isdigit`.  That said, for a programming language parser we probably want to use the `<locales>` version of these, passing `std::locale::classic()` to avoid using the unknown global locale.  That would neatly avoid the bug we have here, where we pass these functions a plain `char` rather than the appropriate positive `int`.

Comment: Thank you for the input. On your points: (1) C++ headers (including <ctype>), indeed, better, will follow, but for the moment at least with MSVS 2022 it is enough to include <iostream> here and with the long mess in these headers, you will get all of them; so this makes sence only with lightweight headers; in my case <string.h> is a legacy from times only CRT exsited, will remove, of course; (2) taking into account the way both `size_t` and `std::size_t` defined, I would stay with shorter version so far;

Comment: (3) not sure what do you mean with passing the locale (`std::locale::classic()`); do you mean you conisder passing it as a second argument for calls? (4) Where do you see a **bug** with passing `char` instead of `int`? Don't [implicit coversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) exist?

Comment: The `<cctype>` functions take a _positive_ int, even on platforms where `char` is signed.  It's a bug to pass a negative char to these functions, as it will be widened to a negative `int`.  Instead we need to convert to `unsigned char` so that widening to `int` produces a positive value.  And yes, the `<locale>` functions such as [`std::isalpha()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalpha) take the locale as second argument (and you can pass plain `char` as first argument, unlike the corresponding `<cctype>` functions).

Comment: Thank you for the explanations on the `<cctype>`, will be on guard here. The problem with the second argument for locale I covered [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289151/fast-tolower-function) (mentioned in the question and you participated in the discussion); it is quite slow, so anyway I will use `fast_tolower` as a wrapper using your advice in both topics. I was in two minds if I need to overcomplicate code here with this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help here. I've updated the code taking into account your recommendations and posted [Rev2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289428/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-2). Could you please revisit it?