# Natural language text fast tokenizer (Rev.2)

Tags: c++, parsing

This is the second iteration of the [Natural language text fast tokenizer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289413/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer/) code review. Special thanks goes to *G. Sliepen* and *Toby Speight* who conducted the first review.

**Functional specification**

Implement a function for fast tokenization of text in char[] buffer handling some natural language specifics below:

1. Consider ‘ ‘ (space) as a delimiter, keeping a way to extends the list of delimiters later.
2. Extract stable collocations like “i.e.”, “etc.”, “…” as a single lexem.
3. In case word contains characters like ‘-‘ and ‘’’ (examples: semi-column, half-, cat’s) return the whole construct as a whole lexem. (3.1) Otherwise, split word and return parts as separate lexems and each non-alphanumeric "inword" symbols as separate lexems.
4. Return sequences of numbers (integers without signs) as a single lexem.

Performance is critical, since the amount of data is huge. The function should be thread-safe.

*Note: The defect in specification was found by Matthieu M in question for first code review when I already posted current Rev.2.: any "inword" non-alphanumeric character except described in item 3 above returns as separate lexems which contradicted original functional specification. Since I still in two minds about behaviour I want here, the item 3.1 has been added which describes how it works now. If you change the code and removing 3.1 to keep lexems with internal non-alphanumeric as a whole (like "a|b") will simplify the code, please feel free to fix on the fly. I will fix this in Rev3.*

**Answers/comments on the items in the first Code Review iteration**

1. I am not sure we need `tokenize` function since we can just use `TokenRange(sample)`; why do we need a wrapper here? Any purpose or risks without it?
2. Thank you for the explanation on the full `std::ranges` approach. Taking into account that I will need to use the tokenized with the execution policies which are still missing in `std::ranges`, I will stay with current implementation so far; considering to make view just for learning ranges/views/projections.
3. The question about [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) library usage is still on the table. Isn’t regex the tool intended exactly for these purposes? Shouldn’t the code with regex be shorter in times? The only concern is performance, which I mentioned in the first post.
4. I decided not to inherit `Iterator` to `std::iterator` because of KISS principle; so far I don’t see any benefits from it. When I see how this could be really used, I will rework this as a separate exercise.

**Changelog**

1. The code reworked to ranges approach with `TokenRange`.
2. To avoid offset recalculation for operator++, the mutable `next` field introduced.
3. Recent C++ features used including switching to `std::isdigit` and `std::isalpha`.

**Concerns**

1. The main issue is this `Iterator::end()`. In the [tutorials](https://internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp) they say that the best approach is to transparently pass the `end()` iterator of underlying data, but since here I can’t return `data.end()`, the empty range is returned and I am still in two minds if `end()` is the only case when empty range could occur, so this could lead to false-positive check to `end()` if I am correct. Please, comment.
2. Mutable `next` to pass the offset from `operator*` to `operator++` is not the best solution here, but I don’t see anything better. Any suggestions?
3. Still don’t like the code in the inner while loop in the `TokenRange::Iterator::operator*`. It is hard to grasp and prove to be correct, but don’t see any way to simplify it.
4. Still not sure if class `Iterator` is the best place for these `dilimiters`, `stable_lexems` and `inword_lexems`; I want them to be configurable later, but still in two minds if they should belong to `TokenRange` or to `Iterator`, since formally they don’t define the range, but the way to iterate the range. On the other hand, any hardcoded values is evil, so I should request them in constructor and I don’t want to have them in every iterator’s ctor. Putting them into `TokenRange` and copy to `Iterator` on creation to be able to adjust seems as overengineering.

**The code**

Here is the updated code for the code review; could you please take a look and suggest further ways to improve?

Fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bnrfE46r7).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

class TokenRange {
    std::string_view data;
public:
    class Iterator {
        const std::string_view delimiters = " ";
        const std::vector<std::string_view> stable_lexems = { "i.e.", "etc.", "..." };
        const std::string_view inword_lexems = "-\'";

        std::string_view data;
        mutable size_t next = ((size_t)-1);
    public:
        Iterator(std::string_view data = {}) : data(data) { skip_delimiters(); }
        std::string_view operator*() const;
        Iterator& operator++();
        friend bool operator==(const Iterator& it1, const Iterator& it2) { return it1.data == it2.data; }
    private:
        void skip_delimiters();
    };

    TokenRange(std::string_view data) : data(data) {}

    Iterator begin() {
        return Iterator(data);
    }

    Iterator end() {
        return {};
    }
};

void TokenRange::Iterator::skip_delimiters()
{
    size_t skip = 0;
    while (skip < data.size() && std::ranges::contains(delimiters, data[skip])) {
        ++skip;
    }

    data.remove_prefix(skip);
}

std::string_view TokenRange::Iterator::operator*() const
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while (!data.empty() && i == 0) {
        auto it = std::ranges::find_if(stable_lexems, [&](auto stable_lexem)
            {
                return data.starts_with(stable_lexem);
            });

        if (it != stable_lexems.end()) {
            next = it->size()+(data.size()-data.size());
            return data.substr(0, it->size());
        }

        while (i < data.size() && !std::ranges::contains(delimiters, data[i])) {
            const bool is_inword_char = std::ranges::contains(inword_lexems, data[i]);

            if (is_inword_char && i != 0 && std::isalpha(data[i - 1])) {
                ++i;
                continue;
            }

            if (!std::isalpha(data[i]) && !std::isdigit(data[i])) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    ++i;
                }
                break;
            }

            ++i;
        }
    }

    next = i + (data.size() - data.size());
    return data.substr(0,i);
}

TokenRange::Iterator& TokenRange::Iterator::operator++()
{ 
    if (next == ((size_t)-1)) {
        operator*();
    }

    data.remove_prefix(next);
    skip_delimiters();

    next = ((size_t)-1);

    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    std::string sample = "Let's consider, this semi-simple sample, i.e. test data with ints: 100, etc. For ... some testing...";
        
    for (auto token : TokenRange(sample)) {
        std::cout << token << " | ";
    }
}
```

**Performance**

I was really surprised with the performance results I got with this new code. Tested on my local PC, the new code is about 18% faster than my original code despite the fact that `std::string_view` is at least twice larger (pointer and size) than `const char*`.

I expected the new version to be at least somewhat slower if not dramatically, but it seems that `std::ranges` library does its work best to provide code which compiler could optimize even better than my original code.

So, at least at this stage no ground for being afraid of expenses.

Being honest, I was used to think that low-level C-style which is closer to assembler language should compile better; the reality is different for our luck.

Here is a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o3hPKvnMc) for those who interested in performance measurements.

Please, note that [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) is not suited for performance measurements (at least, as I know it), so the results could differ dramatically. You could just copy the code to your local PC and check.

Comment: You're still misspelling `std::size_t`.  It's not portable to assume that the standard library will define global-namespace equivalents of `std`-namespace identifiers (it's allowed to, but not _required_ to).  And you're still passing possibly-negative characters to `std::isalpha()` and `std::isdigit()`.  It doesn't look like you've taken advice.

Comment: @TobySpeight, thank you for the input. I was sure your point was that `isalpha()` is not safe and switching to `std::isalpha()` should solve the problem alongside with moving to `std` functions. I will check more careful this time and will make the adjustment. On the `std::size_t`, as I answered in my comment to your previous answer, taking into account how `std::size_t` defined I made conscious decision to use `size_t`. Please see the standard 17.7/2 and 18.1/3 which makes them absolutely interchangeable and portable. Someday I could change my mind, but so far `size_t` is enough for me.

Comment: Previous review was more concerned with the difference between [`std::isalpha()` from `<cctype>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) and [`std::isaplha` from `<locales>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalpha).  The latter can be used directly with plain `char` but not the former.

Comment: You have no definition in scope for `size_t`, only `std::size_t`.  If you really need an unqualified version, you need to include a C compatibility header or to write `using std::size_t;`.  It is _not portable_ to assume that `size_t` is defined everywhere that `std::size_t` is.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I've published the [Rev.3]( https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289472/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-3) which covers all your points. Could you please take a look? Please pay special attention to Reservation 2; since it related to singed/unsigned problem, maybe you could help me realize why CLang is unhappy with `unsigned char` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've make a partial review below. It's only partial, because it's become clear that the code is a bit too much work in progress. Not only the formatting, but also the correctness. Further, that also makes it pretty hard to follow. In general, it would help if you sometimes described in prose what a section of code does. I believe the `size-size` issue below was caused by refactoring and changing the meaning of code, too. Having those comments and proof-reading them afterwards helps avoid these issues. That said, despite these flaws, your code is not a mess and generally well-structured.

### Formatting Consistency

Sometimes you put the opening `{` and closing `}` on the same line with the function header, sometimes only the opening `{` and sometimes neither. Use one style consistently. Don't cram too much into one line. The compiler won't generate smaller or faster code for it, but it will make the code harder to read and understand.

### Cornercase Skipping Space Characters

The function skipping the initial spaces will fail if there is only spaces. I'd rewrite it like this:

```
while (true) {
    if (input is empty) {
        break;
    }
    if (input[0] is not a delimiter) {
        break;
    }
    input.drop_prefix(1);
}
```

Putting multiple condition checks into the `while` condition won't generate smaller or faster code. It does make it less readable which in turn makes it more likely that you miss errors.

### Use Of C-Style Casts

I'm referring to `((size_t)-1)`, which is bad for two reasons. Firstly, it's a magic number. Secondly, it uses C-style casts. Using a named constant (`npos` for example) would be much more readable.

### Mutable Data

You raised the question concerning the mutable `next` yourself and whether it's necessary. I don't think it is. If you look at what's happening on the input sequence, you find these steps:

1. skip separators
2. find end of token to process it
3. skip to end of token
4. go to step 1

I've ignore the checks for EOF here for now, since it's not important here. The point is that step 2 (`operator *`) assumes a constant iterator. However, it must store the end of the token for step 3 (`operator ++`) in order to not repeat the forward scan there.

As alternative, I'd combine skipping separators and scanning for the end of the token. So, in the constructor, you do that once from the initial position and remember both the start and end of the token. `operator*` then just returns the subsequence you determined there. `operator++` then drops the determined token from the head of the sequence and then searches for the next exactly like the constructor.

As additional benefit, multiple or zero calls to `operator*` will be handled much more gracefully.

### Unicode Compliance

Is that even a goal for you? If your input is plain ASCII, quite a few things simplify. For example, all the locale-specific `is*` can much easier be implemented as `ranges::contains()` calls.

### Skipping Stable Lexems

The code there does `(data.size()-data.size())`, which makes no sense to me, it's zero. Does this even work correctly?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help here! I agree with many points, but let me postpone the acceptance before I clarify some moments. Let me address them one by one. (1) I believe that the code which need be commented (at least such simple code) is ill-written, so I avoid comments as much as possible, but let me think of it in terms of code review;

Comment: (2) I believe, my code is mostly consistently formatted according to my style; with this I mean that the same things are formatted similarly. I prefer dense code because I like to see everything in one screen without scrolling. Let's look at the final version when it comes and if you show me better formatting, I would be thankful;

Comment: (3) I can't see why `skip_delimiters()` could fail because of "only delimiters"; just tested, everything works just fine. Don't see a reason for 9 lines instead of 5 with multiple `remove_prefix` calls. For me the condition in while is C/C++-classic, used everywhere and well-readable; can provide many examples from the C++ standard library.

Comment: (4) is* functions works even faster with my [Fast tolower function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289151/fast-tolower-function) as I mentioned in rev1, I just avoided code overcomplication here. Totally agree with all other your points and especially love your solution for `operator*()` and `operator++()`. I will implement all this in rev.3.

Comment: Hey @DamirTenishev, thanks for the feedback. Concerning the `skip_delimiters()`, it works. I'm not sure what I saw there. Concernig the multiple `remove_prefix()` calls, they boil down to a pointer adjustment operation that I'd expect to be inlined. So, using `data.empty()` and `data.remove_prefix(1)` and `data.front()` would be the way to go. If you insist on it, you can also keep that while-loop structure with it: `while (!data.empty() && is_separator(data.front())) data.remove_prefix(1);`.

Comment: Thank you for the improvement suggestion, I've applied it in the code as well as all other your recommendations. Special thanks for the idea with the approach with `operator*()` and `operator++()`, it really made code much better now. I've published the [Rev.3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289472/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-3). Could you please take a look?

Comment: Just to be on the same page, now [Rev.5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289511/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-5) is the actual version.