# Natural language text fast tokenizer (Rev.3)

Tags: c++, parsing

This is the third iteration of the [Natural language text fast tokenizer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289428/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-2) code review. Special thanks goes to *G. Sliepen*, *Toby Speight* and *uli* who conducted previous reviews and to *Matthieu M.* and *Adrian McCarthy* who participated with important findings.

**Functional specification**

Implement a function for fast text tokenization handling some natural language specifics below:

1. Consider ‘ ‘ (space) as a delimiter, keeping a way to extend the list of delimiters later; the delimiters couldn’t be a part of other constructs.
2. Extract stable collocations like “i.e.”, “etc.”, “…” as a single lexem.
3. In case word contains “inword” characters like ‘-‘ and ‘’’ (examples: semi-column, half-, cat’s) return the whole construct as a whole lexem.
4. Threat all other non-alphanumeric characters as separate lexems.
5. Return sequences of numbers (integers without signs) as a single lexem.
   Performance is critical, since the amount of data is huge. The function should be thread-safe.

**Changes**

1. The code has been reworked according to most of code review points.
2. The only exception is brackets `{` and `}` formatting consistency; I am still in two minds if my approach somewhere should be replaced with lengthier one.
3. I added the [fast::isalpha](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289151/fast-tolower-function) (12% faster than std::isalpha) (works in assumption of 8-bit encoding) and fast::isdigit (5% faster than std::isdigit, although a little bit risky). Of course, not these percents is a point here, but the dramatic slowdown of these `std` operations when it comes to work with some specific locale.

**Concerns**

1. The only place I still don’t like is this calculation of `offset` in `operator++()`, but I can’t see the better way:

```
    if (!lexem.empty()) {
        std::size_t offset = lexem.data() - data.data() + lexem.size();
        data.remove_prefix(offset);
    }
```

**Reservations**

1. Methods implementation inside of the class definition done only to the sake of brevity; production code will have them implemented separately.
2. I have no idea why in `set_locale` when `auto const func` compiled with Clang with `[&locale](unsigned char c)` leads to 'std::bad_cast' while with MSVC it works just fine; the only way Clang works is with `[&locale](char c)`, even `[&locale](unsigned int c)` doesn’t work. So, I have to leave this as is on godbolt.org. If you know the reason, please help me to fix to make this portable.

**The code**

Here is the updated code for the code review; could you please take a look and suggest further ways to improve or confirm that this is ready to go code?

Fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9rnaco4P4).

```
#include <algorithm>    
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

namespace fast {
    class IsAlpha
    {
        std::array<unsigned char, std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() + 1> cache = {};

    public:
        explicit IsAlpha(const std::locale& locale = {})
        {
            set_locale(locale);
        }

        void set_locale(const std::locale& locale)
        {
            auto const func = [&locale](unsigned char c) { return std::isalpha(c, locale); };
            std::ranges::copy(std::views::iota(0u, cache.size())
                | std::views::transform(func),
                cache.begin());
        }

        bool operator()(unsigned char c) const { return cache[c]; }
    };

    IsAlpha isalpha;

    bool isdigit(unsigned char c) { return c >= '0' && c <= '9'; }
}

class TokenRange {
    std::string_view data;
public:
    class Iterator {
        const std::string_view delimiters = " ";
        const std::vector<std::string_view> stable_lexems = { "i.e.", "etc.", "..." };
        const std::string_view inword_symbols = "-\'";

        std::string_view data;
        std::string_view lexem;
    public:
        Iterator() {}
        Iterator(std::string_view data) : data(data) { extract_lexem(); }
        std::string_view operator*() const { return lexem; }
        Iterator& operator++();
        friend bool operator==(const Iterator& it1, const Iterator& it2) { return it1.data == it2.data; }
    private:
        void extract_lexem();
    };

    TokenRange(std::string_view data) : data(data) {}

    Iterator begin() {
        return Iterator(data);
    }

    Iterator end() {
        return {};
    }
};

void TokenRange::Iterator::extract_lexem()
{
    while (!data.empty() && std::ranges::contains(delimiters, data.front())) {
        data.remove_prefix(1);
    }

    auto it = std::ranges::find_if(stable_lexems, [&](auto stable_lexem) 
        {
            return data.starts_with(stable_lexem);
        });

    if (it != stable_lexems.end()) {
        lexem = data.substr(0, it->size());
        return;
    }

    std::size_t index = 0;
    while (index < data.size()) 
    {
        if (std::ranges::contains(delimiters, data[index])) {
            break;
        }

        const bool is_not_alphanumeric = !fast::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(data[index])) && !fast::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(data[index]));
        if (is_not_alphanumeric) {
            if (index == 0) {
                ++index;
            }
            break;
        }

        const bool is_next_char_inword_symbol = (index+1) < data.size() ? std::ranges::contains(inword_symbols, data[index+1]) : false;

        if (is_next_char_inword_symbol) {
            ++index;
        }

        ++index;
    }

    lexem = data.substr(0, index);
}

TokenRange::Iterator& TokenRange::Iterator::operator++()
{
    if (!lexem.empty()) {
        std::size_t offset = lexem.data() - data.data() + lexem.size();
        data.remove_prefix(offset);
    }
    extract_lexem();
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::string sample = "Let's consider, this semi-simple sample, i.e. test data with ints: 100 and 0x20u, etc. For ... some testing...";

        for (auto token : TokenRange(sample)) {
            std::cout << token << " | ";
        }
    }
}
```

**Performance**

For those who interested in performance evaluations, here is the [code with tests](https://godbolt.org/z/do43ev4WT).

Please, note that [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) is not suited for performance measurements (at least, as I know it), so the results could differ dramatically. You could just copy the code to your local PC and check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answers to your questions

> ###### Concerns
>
> 1. The only place I still don’t like is this calculation of offset in `operator++()`, but I can’t see the better way:

I think it's a very minor issue. However, if you want to get rid of it in `operator++()`, I would make `extract_lexem()` update `data` directly. Then the only issue is that `data` is used in `operator==()`. But instead of comparing two whole string views there, consider just comparing the `lexem.data()` pointers to each other:

```
friend bool operator==(const Iterator& it1, const Iterator& it2) {
    return it1.lexem.data() == it2.lexem.data();
}
```

> ###### Reservations
>
> 1. Methods implementation inside of the class definition done only to the sake of brevity; production code will have them implemented separately.

I personally don't mind if short functions are defined inside the class if it's going to be all header-only, but otherwise they should indeed be defined separately in a source file.

> 2. I have no idea why in `set_locale` when `auto const func` compiled with Clang with `[&locale](unsigned char c)` leads to 'std::bad_cast' […]

See Toby Speight's answer.

## Why is `fast::isdigit()` not locale-aware?

It's really weird to see you set up a cache for a locale-aware `isalpha()`, but then have a very simple `isdigit()` that just assumes digits are always like in US-ASCII. Are you really sure that's the case for all possible locales?

## Move casting into `fast::isalpha()`/`isdigit()`

I would make `fast::isalpha()` and `fast::isidigit()` take a regular `char` as a parameter, and have those functions do the casting to `unsigned char`. That simplifies the code using it.

## Split up `extract_lexem()`

Consider splitting up some of the code in `extract_lexem()` into separate functions. For example, the first three lines could be put into a `skip_delimiters()` function. This helps simplify `extract_lexem()` and also provides self-documentation.

## About in-word lexems

Natural language is messy. I see why you want to be able to parse `Let's` as one token. But what if they are used as single quotes, like in `'foo'` or `'hello world'`? A trailing apostrophe is considered to be in-word by your tokenizer. And my examples here are where you don't want to consider that as part of a word, but in English you can have a trailing apostrophe when you have a plural of a possessive noun, like in `the parents' children`. And other languages might have very different rules.

Comment: Thank you for the review. Let me address some of topics one by one before I make a revision 4. (1) On the `fast::isdigit` I wrote above “although a little bit risky”, but I intentionally made this decision, since if I’d implemented in cached way somebody for sure would come with comment “don’t overengineer” and Suzhou numerals won’t persuade them. Anyway, let’s consider this as “example for brevity” here; I totally agree with your point.

Comment: (2) I intentionally made casting in extract_lexem code in order to simplify switching between `std` and `fast` versions for performance measurement; the production code uses `char`. (3) On function extraction, I am still in twenty minds here if 3 lines of code worth a new function; I love self-documenting, but having a dozen of extra functions (in a typical, not this situation) in the same “namespace” seems to be a high price for this. I will reword and compare, but I am still not sure here that’s why I inlined `skip_delimiters()` code into `extract_lexem()`.

Comment: (4) On in-word lexems and paired lexems, it is even worse, since English use quotes for dialogues and this comes to a huge task or pairing and handling pairing errors in texts, as well as intentional unpairing like with `”`. So, this is above this simple parser which works fine with `parents’`, but, really can’t handle context. Let’s leave this for lexical parsing level if it comes to, keeping this syntactic parser simple. Of course, I agree with you here.

Comment: I looked for where C++ guarantees that the basic digits `'0'..'9'` are consecutive as in C, but failed to find it.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Why is having more functions "a high price"? As long as they are `private`, they don't affect the API nor ABI, and they will be inlined so there is no performance overhead.

Comment: @TobySpeight, unfortunately, they are not guaranteed and one of the examples is [Suzhou numerals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570119/does-unicode-guarantee-that-numeral-codepoints-are-consecutive). Of course, today I am hard to imagine I would work with them, but I remember that "640K is more memory than anyone will ever need"...

Comment: Function extraction is one of the hardest problems for me and I am very interested in your help here. See my reasoning. (1) Yes, they are private, but they visible for all members of this class; let’s imagine a class with a function with complex calculations (find intersections of geometrical primitives); I will extract 50 functions and this will be a mess of functions visible in this class.

Comment: (2) I am not worried about performance overhead, but I am worried about source file size. Instead of 150 lines of large function I will have 400 lines of 50 small functions to be written, documented, learned, remembered and read by others. Well, I exaggerating to explain the idea, but I had the cases.

Comment: (3) Most of these functions don’t have any meaning outside of the large function context, so it is hard to name and document them, since function `find_left_upper_corner_of_frastum_and_horizon_intersection()` is crazy and preconditions like “array must be sorted, all characters must be lowercase”, etc. could be deadly and function without them could be dangerous if used by another developer in support.

Comment: (4) People always say, “you are human, find the balance!”, but when it is suggested to extract 3 lines of code to a separate function, making it 7 lines of code, where is a balance? What about Occam’s razor? (end-of-list). To put in a nutshell, I love functional decomposition, I see that most of good software uses it, but until some technique invented better than “just nest a ‘utils’ or ‘details’ structure or namespace”, I will be in twenty minds about over-extracting functions. Please help me, if you have good recommendation here. Again, this list is short, just issues “on a surface”.

Comment: I am not sure `return it1.lexem.data() == it2.lexem.data();` in the `operator==()` would work, since the main goal of it in our case to compare with iterator returned by `end()` and it returns default constructed `std::string_view` which `data()` is nullptr and when lexem gets empty it returns `std::string_view` with a very specific address of an empty string `'\0'`. It wouldn't have worked even if default constructed were initialized by another very specific address. The `return it1.data == it2.data;` should work, still.

Comment: All points have been applied in the [Rev.4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289487/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-4). Please take a look and let me know if function extraction could be usefully continued; I did my best.

Answer (score 5):

We're missing includes of `<locale>` and `<limits>`.  It *is not portable* to assume any transitive includes of standard library headers except those few specifically prescribed in the C++ standard.

This looks wrong:

> ```
>  [&locale](unsigned char c) { return std::isalpha(c, locale); };
> ```

The `std::isalpha()` function from `<cctype>` accepts `unsigned char`.

But here, we're using the `std::isalpha()` template function from `<locales>`.  The template is specialised for the *character types* `char` and `wchar_t`.  C++ does not require a specialisation for `unsigned char`, so we need a cast there:

```
         std::isalpha(static_cast<char>(c), locale);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have two points here. (1) I agree on the includes; the question is if there some way (except reading documentation for each and every function) to see which includes are necessary? It works when I add includes, but when I do clean up it is very easy to remove include which is used in some place of a long source file. (2) I see. That's why I missed the whole story about converting types in my previous revisions, I used these functions and `char` cascaded till that point without any conversions.

Comment: I think the `iwyu` ("include what you use") tool helps to identify missing and extraneous includes, but I've hardly used it - I mostly just rely on documentation, memory and inspection.

Comment: Applied in the [Rev.4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289487/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-4) by removing all casts to `unsigned char`, hope I got this right. Thank you again.

Comment: Just to be on the same page, now [Rev.5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289511/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-5) is the actual version.