# Natural language text fast tokenizer (Rev.4)

Tags: c++, parsing

This is the forth iteration of the [Natural language text fast tokenizer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289472/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-3/) code review. Special thanks goes to *G. Sliepen*, *Toby Speight* and *uli* who conducted previous reviews and to *Matthieu M.* and *Adrian McCarthy* who participated with important findings.

**Functional specification**

Implement a class for fast text tokenization handling some natural language specifics below:

1. Consider ‘ ‘ (space) as a delimiter, keeping a way to extend the list of delimiters later; the delimiters couldn’t be a part of other constructs.
2. Extract stable collocations like “i.e.”, “etc.”, “…” as a single lexem.
3. In case word contains “inword” characters like ‘-‘ and ‘’’ (examples: semi-column, half-, cat’s) return the whole construct as a whole lexem.
4. Threat all other non-alphanumeric characters as separate lexems.
5. Return sequences of numbers (integers without signs) as a single lexem.

Consider out of scope paired quotes and other lexical parsing level issues.

Performance is critical, since the amount of data is huge. The function should be thread-safe.

**Changes**

1. The code has been reworked according to most of code review points.
2. The only exception is brackets `{` and `}` formatting consistency; I am still in two minds if my approach somewhere should be replaced with lengthier one.

**Reservations**

1. Methods implementation inside of the class definition done only to the sake of brevity; production code will have them implemented separately.

**The code**

Here is the updated code for the code review; could you please take a look and suggest further ways to improve or confirm that this is ready to go code?

Fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3bo4c8q84).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <locale>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

namespace fast {
    template <typename Fn>
    class IsSomething
    {
        std::array<char, std::numeric_limits<char>::max() + 1> cache = {};

    public:
        explicit IsSomething(Fn fn, const std::locale& locale = {})
        {
            set_locale(fn, locale);
        }

        void set_locale(Fn fn, const std::locale& locale)
        {
            auto const func = [&locale, &fn](char c) { return fn(c, locale); };
            std::ranges::copy(std::views::iota(0u, cache.size())
                | std::views::transform(func),
                cache.begin());
        }

        bool operator()(char c) const { return cache[c]; }
    };

    IsSomething isalpha(std::isalpha<char>);
    IsSomething isdigit(std::isdigit<char>);

    bool is_not_alphanumeric(char c) {
        return !fast::isalpha(c)
            && !fast::isdigit(c);
    }
}

class TokenRange {
    std::string_view data;
public:
    class Iterator {
        const std::string_view delimiters = " ";
        const std::vector<std::string_view> stable_lexems = { "i.e.", "etc.", "..." };
        const std::string_view inword_symbols = "-\'";

        std::string_view data;
        std::string_view lexem;
    public:
        Iterator() {}
        Iterator(std::string_view data) : data(data) { extract_lexem(); }
        std::string_view operator*() const { return lexem; }
        Iterator& operator++();
        friend bool operator==(const Iterator& it1, const Iterator& it2) { return it1.data == it2.data; }
    private:
        void extract_lexem();
        void skip_delimiters();
        bool check_for_stable_lexems();
    };

    TokenRange(std::string_view data) : data(data) {}

    Iterator begin() {
        return Iterator(data);
    }

    Iterator end() {
        return {};
    }
};

void TokenRange::Iterator::skip_delimiters()
{
    while (!data.empty() && std::ranges::contains(delimiters, data.front())) {
        data.remove_prefix(1);
    }
}

bool TokenRange::Iterator::check_for_stable_lexems()
{
    auto it = std::ranges::find_if(stable_lexems, 
        [&](auto stable_lexem) {
            return data.starts_with(stable_lexem);
        });

    if (it != stable_lexems.end()) {
        lexem = data.substr(0, it->size());
        data = data.substr(it->size());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void TokenRange::Iterator::extract_lexem()
{
    skip_delimiters();

    if (check_for_stable_lexems()) {
        return;
    }

    std::size_t index = 0;
    while (index < data.size()) 
    {
        if (std::ranges::contains(delimiters, data[index])) {
            break;
        }

        if (fast::is_not_alphanumeric(data[index])) {
            if (index == 0) {
                ++index;
            }
            break;
        }

        const bool is_next_char_inword_symbol = (index+1) < data.size() ? std::ranges::contains(inword_symbols, data[index+1]) : false;
        if (is_next_char_inword_symbol) {
            ++index;
        }

        ++index;
    }

    lexem = data.substr(0, index);
    data = data.substr(index);
}

TokenRange::Iterator& TokenRange::Iterator::operator++()
{
    extract_lexem();
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    std::string sample = "Let's consider, this cats' semi-simple sample, i.e. test data with ints: 100 and 0x20u, etc. For ... some testing...";

    for (auto token : TokenRange(sample)) {
        std::cout << token << " | ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It doesn't output the last token

Your own demo shows that it is not printing the last token `...`.

## Missing test suite

You should create a test suite that tests your `class TokenRange`. It could look like:

```
int main() {
    struct {
        std::string input;
        std::vector<std::string> expected;
    } samples = {
        {"Hello, world!", {"Hello", ",", "world", "!"}},
        …
    };

    for (auto& sample: samples) {
        assert(std::ranges::equal(TokenRange(sample.input), sample.expected));
    }
}
```

Make sure you test all the features of your tokenizer, like the stable lexems and in-word lexems, different locales, and corner cases like an empty input, input with only delimiters, and so on.

But the above code also doesn't compile, which brings me to:

## It's not a valid `std::ranges::input_iterator`

While iterating over a `TokenRange` works, algorithms like `std::ranges:equal()` don't because you are not fulfilling all of the requirements of [`std::ranges::input_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/input_range). In particular, it is because your `TokenRange::Iterator` is not a valid [`std::ranges::input_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_iterator).

Because of this, your `TokenRange` will fail to work with many standard algorithms and views. Make sure you fulfill all the requirements. In particular, your iterator needs a post-increment operator and the member type `difference_type` to be defined.

## Some nitpicking

- `IsSomething` doesn't sound like a good name. Everything is something, so it's meaningless. A better name would be `CharacterClass`.
- Avoid negative names. So instead of `is_not_alphanumeric()`, prefer `is_alphanumeric()`, and the caller can then just use `!` to invert the meaning.
- An even better name is `isalnum()`, to match [`std::isalnum()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalnum).

Comment: Thank you so much for the new review. I am sure that the comparisons could be done with `std::equal` based on the existing functionality of the `TokenRange` / `TokenRange::Iterator`, but I took the chance to get some practice with 'std::ranges'-style implementations. Please see the [Rev.5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289511/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-5); defects fixed; tests added. I will be thankful for your input on function extraction comments in [Rev.3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289472/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-3/).